# Plotting missing data

Tags: r, plot, missing-data, locf

I'm trying plotting the following imputed dataset with LOCF method, according this procedure

```
> dati
# A tibble: 27 x 6
      id sex      d8   d10   d12   d14
   <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1 F      21    20    21.5  23  
 2     2 F      21    21.5  24    25.5
 3     3 NA     NA    24    NA    26  
 4     4 F      23.5  24.5  25    26.5
 5     5 F      21.5  23    22.5  23.5
 6     6 F      20    21    21    22.5
 7     7 F      21.5  22.5  23    25  
 8     8 F      23    23    23.5  24  
 9     9 F      NA    21    NA    21.5
10    10 F      16.5  19    19    19.5
# ... with 17 more rows

dati_locf <- dati %>% mutate(across(everything(),na.locf)) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(),na.locf,fromlast = T))

apply(dati_locf[which(dati_locf$sex=="F"),1:4], 1, function(x) lines(x, col = "green"))
```

Howrever, when I run the last line to plot dataset it turns me back both these error and warning messages:

```
Warning in xy.coords(x, y) : a NA has been produced by coercion
Error in plot.xy(xy.coords(x, y), type = type, ...) : 
  plot.new has not been called yet
Called from: plot.xy(xy.coords(x, y), type = type, ...)
```

Can you explain why and how I could fix them? I let you attach the page I has been being address to after running it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRJYY.png)

Comment: Please read the information at the top of the [tag:r] tag page and in particular show your input using `dput` so that it is reproducible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to plot the LOCF imputation for one variable to see how good the fit for the imputations looks for this one variable, you can use the following:

```
library(imputeTS)
# Example 1: Visualize imputation by LOCF
imp_locf <- na_locf(tsAirgap)
ggplot_na_imputations(tsAirgap, imp_locf)
```

[image]

tsAirgap is an time series example, which comes with the imputeTS package. You would have to replace this with the time series / variable you want to plot. Imputed values are shown in red. As you can see, for this series last observation carried forward would be kind of ok, but there are algorithms tat come with the imputeTS package, that give a better result (e.g. na_kalman or na_seadec). Here is also an example of next observation carried backward, since you also used NOCB.

```
library(imputeTS)
# Example 2: Visualize imputation by NOCB
imp_locf <- na_locf(tsAirgap, option = "nocb")
ggplot_na_imputations(tsAirgap, imp_locf)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems here:

- `apply` will convert its first argument to matrix and since the second column is character it gives a character matrix. Clearly one can't plot that with `lines`.
- presumably we want to plot columns 3:6, not 1:4
- `na.locf` will produce multiple values that are the same wherever there is an NA but what we really want is to connect non-NA points.  Use `na.approx` instead.
- `lines` can only be used after `plot` but there is no `plot` command.  Use `matplot` instead.

Making these changes we have the following.

```
library(zoo)
# see Note below for dati in reproducible form
matplot(na.approx(dati[3:6]), type = "l", ylab = "")
legend("topright", names(dati)[3:6], col = 1:4, lty = 1:4)
```

(continued after plot)
[image: screenshot]

We could alternately use ggplot2 graphics.  First convert to zoo and then use `na.approx` and `autoplot`.  Omit `facet=NULL` if you want separate panels.

```
library(ggplot2)
autoplot(na.approx(zoo(dati[3:6])), facet = NULL)
```

### Note

We provide dati in reproducible form below. Note that the `sex` column only contains `NA` and `F` so in the absence of direction it will assume those are a logical NA and FALSE.  Instead we specify that the `sex` column is character in the `read.table` line.

```
Lines <- "
      id sex      d8   d10   d12   d14
 1     1 F      21    20    21.5  23  
 2     2 F      21    21.5  24    25.5
 3     3 NA     NA    24    NA    26  
 4     4 F      23.5  24.5  25    26.5
 5     5 F      21.5  23    22.5  23.5
 6     6 F      20    21    21    22.5
 7     7 F      21.5  22.5  23    25  
 8     8 F      23    23    23.5  24  
 9     9 F      NA    21    NA    21.5
10    10 F      16.5  19    19    19.5"
dati <- read.table(text = Lines, colClasses = list(sex = "character"))
```

Comment: I kindly thank you for providing your answer. It was pretty educational. However, I need to go through the analysis just under the condition I've described above. So if you have any clue about it, that should be great too.